# getting the columnname and sum the values in datatable c#

Tags: c#, datatable

```
for (int i = 9; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    string dtcolumn = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();

    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM( " + dtcolumn + " )", "  " + dtcolumn + " > 0"));
}
```

it is working when column values are not null. but sometimes throwing invalidcastexception  and displaying Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.how to avoid invalidcastexception

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, at least not with the part you have posted. You need to tell us how to reproduce your issue.

Comment: you can try `dt.Compute("SUM(IsNull([" + dtcolumn + "], 0))"` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression

Answer (score 0):

You should add a null check like what @sajeetharan has said but the null check he has mentioned may not work because this is ADO.NET. You should check for null using DBNull.

Something like this

```
for (int i = 9; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if(!DBNull.Value.Equals(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName))
    {
        string dtcolumn = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM( " + dtcolumn + " )", "  " + dtcolumn + " > 0"));
     } 
 }
```

Comment: You do not need DBNull to check if the name of the column is null.

Comment: The OP explicitly said that he was getting a `Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types` error.

Comment: Yes the OP did say that but your answer does not address that issue. You are using DBNull to check if a column name is null--that is not how to check it. You do not need DBNull. And even if the column did not exist, the error would be totally different and it will be about column not found.

Comment: But I do not find any other casting in the snippet the OP's provided. What other statement is causing this issue?

Comment: See my comment to the OPs question.

Comment: Oh, ok. So a the ColumnName is a string property that cannot be equal to DBNull

Answer (score 0):

```
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 9; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    if (dt.Rows[j][k].ToString() == "")
                    {
                        dt.Rows[j][k] = "0";
                    }
                }
            }


     for (int i = 9; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
        string dtcolumn = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM( " + dtcolumn + " )", "1 > 0"));

         }
```

thank you ,this code works without trowing any exception

Comment: it is just for filtering purpose. instead of 1>0 u may use string.empty or columnname > 5 or any filter   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I know it is a filter but 1 is always bigger than 0 so what does that get you?

Comment: my goal is not to filter anything, so i put a positive condition there which does not effect my datatable

Comment: But how does that answer your question? How does that get rid of the exception you were facing?

Comment: by hardcoding 1 > 0   its working...  if i put a columnname > 5 im still facing exception...